# Rolling sum with dynamic size of window and skipping first few rows

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I want to calculate a rolling sum and rolling average of my data with the size of the rolling window defined for each row.

For example, suppose I have daily temperature and daily precipitation for different cities. I want to calculate past average temperatures, and past cumulative rain for each city, but the window of analysis change in each row. I also need to calculate past climatic variables, but skipping the first few observations.

The code below helps to give an example of my needs.

```r
set.seed(122)
df <- data.frame(rain = rep(5,10),temp=1:10, skip = sample(0:2,10,T),
                 windw_sz = sample(1:2,10,T),city =c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),ord=rep(c(1:5),2)) 
df
   rain temp skip windw_sz city ord
1     5    1    0        2    a   1
2     5    2    1        1    a   2
3     5    3    2        2    a   3
4     5    4    2        1    a   4
5     5    5    2        2    a   5
6     5    6    0        1    b   1
7     5    7    2        2    b   2
8     5    8    1        2    b   3
9     5    9    2        1    b   4
10    5   10    2        2    b   5
```

In the first line, skip== 0, and window_size ==2, so I should consider variables from today and yesterday. In the second line, skip == 1 and window size ==1, so I need to consider variables from yesterday only. In the third line, skip== 2 and window size == 2, so I should skip variable from today and yesterday, and consider only the two days before yesterday.

Any solution is appreciated, but I would especially enjoy something with data.table.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think data.tables frollsum() should work here:

```
dd <- data.table(value = 1:10,
                 offset = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                 windowsize = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2))

dd[, frollsum(value, windowsize + offset, adaptive=TRUE) - frollsum(value, offset, adaptive=TRUE)]
```

I could not figure out how to make it so that the rolling sum gets 'padded' with 0s if the window size extends the values... setting 'na.rm=TRUE' did not help either.